# Can someone explain this backup script to me?

Tags: batch-file, backup, mysql

I have a batch file for making a backup of my mysqldump, this works. But I don't understand the code. can someone, explain this to me.

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('date /t') do set DATE_DOW=%%i

for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('date /t') do set DATE_DAY=%%i

for /f %%i in ('echo %date_day:/=-%') do set DATE_DAY=%%i
for /f %%i in ('time /t') do set DATE_TIME=%%i
for /f %%i in ('echo %date_time::=-%') do set DATE_TIME=%%i

:: here i make my backup 
"C:\Program Files\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump" -u root mamzel > "C:\Program Files\xampp\mysql\bin\%DATE_DAY%_%DATE_TIME%_mamzel10.sql"
at /delete /yes

at 09:00 /every:maandag,woensdag,donderdag d:\mysqlBackup.bat
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think you should mark @Mechaflash's answer.

Comment: I searched a lot for this code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('date /t') do set DATE_DOW=%%i
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('date /t') do set DATE_DAY=%%i
```

If in the U.S. time format, `date /t` outputs the date as `Wed 02/01/2012` A token (without `delims` specified) will separate that output using spaces as the delimiting factor. So token 1=`Wed` and token 2=`02/01/2012`. So you are assigning `DATE_DOW=Wed` and `DATE_DAY=02/01/2012`. Seeing as the days aren't in English, it's probably formated as year/month/day.

```
for /f %%i in ('echo %date_day:/=-%') do set DATE_DAY=%%i
```

This strips the `/` from the date and replacing it with `-`, so your output is `02-01-2012` as opposed to `02/01/2012`

```
for /f %%i in ('time /t') do set DATE_TIME=%%i
for /f %%i in ('echo %date_time::=-%') do set DATE_TIME=%%i
```

This does the same thing as the first part, except its grabbing the time format. The second line replaces the colons `:` with dashes `-`.

```
"C:\Program Files\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump" -u root mamzel > "C:\Program Files\xampp\mysql\bin\%DATE_DAY%_%DATE_TIME%_mamzel10.sql"
```

This then uses your new date and time formats to dump it to a timestamped dump file.